# How can I include jquery inside my javascript module without conflicting with the global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a javascript module, and I want it to be standalone. I also want to use the cross-browser functionality afforded by jQuery. How can I include jQuery inside my module without conflicting with a potential user-included jQuery?

Is there a general way to do this, so that I can add other libraries to my project without conflicting with the global namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try copying all of jQuery into your JS file and [running it in "no conflict" mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Then, if you wrap your entire JS file in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/) that takes no arguments, your `$` variable won't interfere with the global scope.

So, your file would look something like:

```
(function () {
    // all of jQuery goes here

    $.noConflict();
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    // your code that uses $ here
})();
```

Wrapping everything in the IIFE will keep your `$` variable local and therefore it will not be touchable by any code outside the file. That may be a little bit extreme, but it should work.

### Edit: my above solution is incorrect now that I've tried it out myself.

What you *actually* want to do is just ensure your version of jQuery is included before your user's. Then in your code, run `var myJQ = jQuery.noConflict();` and use `myJQ` in place of `$` or `jQuery` in your code. [See this example.](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/)